# ASP.NET Core WebAPI default route not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've followed several examples suggesting that to set my default route in an ASP.NET Core WebAPI project, I need to replace

```
app.UseMvc();
```

with

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Traders", action = "Get" });
});
```

But when I run it defaults to `localhost:54321/api/values` and it should default to `localhost:54321/Traders`

What's wrong?

Comment: check if you have attribute routing

Comment: @Alex I do, but I've deleted the `ValuesController` and there are no attributes that say `api/values`

Comment: You confused two different things. When you run project it will start on  "launchUrl". "launchUrl"  is set to "api/values" in the project template. Nothing to do with MVC route that you changed

Comment: @tmg could you elaborate? I can't find "launchUrl" anywhere.

Comment: check project properties. Debug tab.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As @tmg mentioned, do the following:

Right click your web project -> Select Properties -> Select the Debug tab on the left -> Then edit the 'Launch Url' field to set your own default launch url.

[image: Properties Pane of the project]

Comment: Took me aaagges to find this SO entry - like a lot of people I was messing around with the default route template and not the launch URL!

Comment: @Calanus I think launchSettings works in Azure production. What will be happened in that case?

Comment: Great! Thanks! It is the same to edit your launchSettings.json, "profiles" section, adding 
"launchUrl": "api/values" under your project section.

Answer (score 11):

You can change the default route by modifying LaunchSettings.json file as shown

[image]

Comment: Can you post it as text?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below.

Create a base controller for your API that extends base controller of dotnet core:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public abstract class ControllerApiBase : Controller
    {

    }
}
```

And inherit the base class in your API controllers:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApi.Dtos;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class PingController : ControllerApiBase
    {
        public PingDto Get()
        {
            return new PingDto
            {
                Version = "0.0.0"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't under stand why this doesn't work 
        template: "api/{controller}/{action}",