# Visual studio 2017 cannot debug .Net core web api?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I created a new .Net 2.0 web api project. And then click the "> IIS Express" button to test it. However, I got a popup of Windows Explorer.

```
Windows Explorer has stopped working

A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.

  Close the program
  Debug the program
```

Another window pops up after close the window.

```
Unable to start program 'http://locahost:24175/api/values'.
Invalid prointer
```

However, "Start without debugging" works.

Comment: It works on my computer. Does VS Code work fine?

Comment: VS code works. "Start without debugging" works too.

Comment: Windows Explorer has nothing to do with *IIS*. Windows Explorer is your desktop and your folder windows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, that's why it's so strange. It only happened when "Start debugging (F5)".

Comment: You may need to attach to the process
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer

Comment: @DanielGale I tried to attach it to a chrome process and it got "Unable to attach to the process. An operation is not legal in the current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you deleted the default ValueController without changing your default route. Check this answer on how to change it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731550/837623